# MassTransit Retry policy throws System.NullReferenceException:

Tags: .net, masstransit

For some reason i cant use retry on my consumer im following the example from the docs , im just adding a simple r.Interval<> to my consumer, but it failing on build...not sure why

```
 services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<SyncConsumer>();
            x.AddConsumer<SyncForcadoConsumer>();
        });
        services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(
                "Endpoint=sb://" + busName + ".servicebus.windows.net/;" +
                "SharedAccessKeyName=" + keyName + ";" +
                "SharedAccessKey=" + secret,
                z =>
                {
                    TokenProvider
                        .CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(keyName, secret);
                });
            cfg.UseExtensionsLogging(provider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>());
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "sync-crm-relacionamento",
                e => { e.Consumer<SyncConsumer>(provider); });
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "sync-forcado-crm-relacionamento",
                e =>
                {                        
                    e.Consumer<SyncForcadoConsumer>(provider);

                    e.UseMessageRetry(r =>
                    {
                        r.Handle<ArgumentNullException>();

                    });
                });
        }));
```

but for some reason im getting this error

```
Unhandled Exception: MassTransit.ConfigurationException: An exception occurred during bus creation ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MassTransit.PipeConfigurators.ConsumeContextRetryPipeSpecification`2.Apply(IPipeBuilder`1 builder)
   at MassTransit.ConsumePipeSpecifications.MessageConsumePipeSpecification`1.Apply(ISpecificationPipeBuilder`1 builder)
   at MassTransit.ConsumePipeSpecifications.MessageConsumePipeSpecification`1.BuildMessagePipe(IPipe`1 pipe)
   at MassTransit.Builders.ReceiveEndpointBuilder.ConnectConsumePipe[T](IPipe`1 pipe)
   at MassTransit.ConsumeConnectors.ConsumerConnector`1.MassTransit.ConsumeConnectors.IConsumerConnector.ConnectConsumer[TConsumer](IConsumePipeConnector consumePipe, IConsumerFactory`1 consumerFactory, IConsumerSpecification`1 specification)
   at MassTransit.ConsumeConfigurators.ConsumerConfigurator`1.Configure(IReceiveEndpointBuilder builder)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually specify a retry policy. Valid policies include:

```
e.UseMessageRetry(r =>
{
    r.Interval(5, 100);

    r.Intervals(100, 500, 1000);

    r.Immediate(2);
});
```

Choose one, there are a few others as well, including Exponential, and None.

It's throwing a configuration exception because you didn't actually configure the retry.

The retry usage is covered in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#retry).

Comment: the error stopped but the retry never work =/. I just dropped a r.Immediate(2), and forced a expection on my consumer, but it only calls once

Comment: is the retry when sending the messsage, or when the consumer has recieved a message and has an error while consuming it?

Comment: Retry is configured on receive endpoints and deals with consumption. Order matters, the UseRetry() should be above your consumer. It's a pipeline.